# Adding integer to array of structures after using strtok

Tags: c, types, structure

I'm having trouble adding an integer into my array of structures and I'm not sure how to fix it. The struct looks like

```
struct info{
    char name[20];
    int course[5];
};
```

I read a file using fgets, then tokenize the line by using strtok(), in which I believe it returns type char* type so the tokens read in are `1105` of type char*. I try to add it into my array of structures by converting the token to type int using atoi then storing it by `struct_array[index].course = number;` but I end up getting this error when compiling.

```
hw4bcopy.c: In function ‘create_structures’:
hw4bcopy.c:48:44: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[5]’ from type ‘int’
                 struct_array[index].course = number;
```

I was able to successfully enter a string into the array of structures but the declaration was a bit different so maybe that's why. The declaration to enter the string into the array of structures was `strcpy(struct_array[index].name,token);` so I'm thinking that maybe the way I'm trying to put the integer in the structure is incorrect?

The code all works fine until I try to add the token as a integer.

What I'm doing is

- open file
- send file to function
- tokenize to get tokens of names like `Edward` and `1105`
- add the tokens to the structure of arrays

code is

```
struct info{
    char name[20];
    int course[5];
};


void create_structures(FILE* file);

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("input-hw04b.txt","r");
    FILE* nf = fopen("out2.txt","w+");
    create_structures(fp);

}

void create_structures(FILE* file)
{
    struct info struct_array[30];
    char buffer[100];
    char* del = " .";
    char* token;
    int number,count;int index = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),file) != NULL)
    {
        count = 0;
        token = strtok(buffer,del);
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                strcpy(struct_array[index].name,token);
            }
            if(count == 5)
            {
                number = atoi(token);
                struct_array[index].course = number;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL,del);
            count = count + 1;
        }
        index = index +1;
    }
    int z;
    for (z = 0; z < index; z++)
        printf("%s %s\n",struct_array[z].name,struct_array[z].course);
```

Comment: `int course[5];` --> `int course;`

Comment: wow thanks, forgot to change that

Comment: You really ought to be doing something like `strncpy(struct_array[index].name, token, 19);` so you don't overrun your bounds for name. (tell it not to copy more than 19 chars since we need room for the `'\0'` on the end of the string)

Answer (score 1):

The way you look for an integer in a string is wrong, instead of using a counter, which works only for predictable content, use functions like `isdigit()` and `isprint()` defined in the [ctype.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/) header. I don't know the layout of the file you're trying to read, but i suppose it has this structure:

> Edward .1105 .1320 .7465 .9672 .0123
>
> Steve .2612 .0567 .7242 .87136 .1423

you can try yourself this new version of your code that i've made, it works with this layout and only with one name, so for example:

> Edward .1105 .1320 .Steve .9672 .0123

would produce bad output cause we're storing only one name, and we can't modify the number of int in the text file if we don't change the size of the array; I think it just need another counter variable for that, btw this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 5

struct info{
    char name[20];
    int course[SIZE];
};




void create_structures(FILE* file)
{
    struct info struct_array[30];
    char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct info)* 3);
    char* del = " .";
    char* token;
    int index = 0, c = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer,100,file))
    {
      for(token = strtok(buffer,del); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, del))
        {

            if(isprint(token[0]) && isdigit(token[0]) == 0)
            {
                strcpy(struct_array[index].name,token);
            }
            if(isdigit(token[0]))
            {
                struct_array[index].course[c] = atoi(token);
                c++;
            }
        }
        index = index +1;
        c = 0;
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < index; z++)
    {
        printf("%s ",struct_array[z].name);
          for(int y = 0 ; y < SIZE ; y++)
           {
             printf("%d ",struct_array[z].course[y]);
           }
          printf("\n");
    }
  }

    int main()
      {
          FILE* fp = fopen("input-hw04b.txt","r");
      //  FILE* nf = fopen("out2.txt","w+");
          create_structures(fp);
      }
```